# Convolution of two random varaibles

Tags: probability, random-variables, convolution

Let $X\sim U[0,20]$ and $Y\sim U[5,15]$ two independent random variables.

Calaculate $P(X+Y\leq t)$.

Can anyone help me in this question, I get here:

$\left\{ X+Y\le t\right\} \Rightarrow\left\{ Y\le t-X\right\} \Rightarrow\left\{ X\in\mathbb{R}\right\} \cap\left\{ Y\le t-X\right\} \Rightarrow\\\int\limits _{0}^{20}\frac{1}{20}\left(\int\limits _{5}^{t-x}\frac{1}{10}dy\right)dx=\\\frac{1}{20}\cdot\frac{1}{10}\int\limits _{0}^{20}1\left(\int\limits _{5}^{t-x}1dy\right)dx=\\\frac{1}{200}\int\limits _{0}^{20}1\left(\int\limits _{5}^{t-x}1dy\right)dx$

But I don't know how to continue now.
Thank you!

Comment: $Y\sim ?$. Note that it is a serious error avoiding to state that $X,Y$ are independent or state some dependence structure between the rv's

Comment: @tommik thank you, I fixed.

Comment: see my answer. I left some numbers without simplifying them in order to better explain you the solution

Answer (score 1):

Do a drawing of the domain (a rectangle) and pass through the line $X+Y=t$.

The corresponding CDF is the area under the line multiplied by the joint density

$$F_T(t)=\begin{cases}
0,  & \text{if $t<5$} \\
\frac{1}{200}\cdot\frac{(t-5)^2}{2},  & \text{if $5\leq t<15$} \\
\frac{1}{4}+\cdot\frac{(t-15)\cdot10}{200},  & \text{if $15\leq t<25$} \\
1-\frac{(35-t)^2}{2\cdot200},  & \text{if $25\leq t<35$} \\
1, & \text{if $t\geq 35$}
\end{cases}$$

The 3 areas are obviously

- a triangle
- the triangle with area $\frac{1}{4}$ plus a parallelogram
- 1 minus the remaining triangle

---

Hint: if you find too difficult this exercise try first with the same exercise where $X,Y$ are independent uniform on $[0;1]$ then solve your exercise with this rectangle

---

Here is the drawing

[image]

Comment: I see this site: https://probabilityexam.wordpress.com/2011/05/26/examples-of-convolution-continuous-case/
with related example. But I am not sure for the intiution and how you get these numbers.
The big problem for me is 'how to think about it'

Comment: Added a sample drawing. Hope this help

Comment: Ok thanks. What is the algebric way for get your answer? and can you explain when we get the parallelogram?